# XNA effects and models

Tags: c#, xna

Cross-Post: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22526/xna-effects-and-models-question/22530#22530

I'd like to understand why I get a completely different result when I replace the effects of a model (as suggested by [How To: Draw a Model with a Custom Effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975391%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)) with a BasicEffect that I instantiate myself:

```
var basicEffect = new BasicEffect( game.GraphicsDevice );
basicEffect.EnableDefaultLighting();
foreach (var mesh in _modelHead.Meshes)
    foreach (var part in mesh.MeshParts)
        part.Effect = basicEffect;
```

My goal is of course to use an effect of my own later, but for the moment I'd really like to understand what's going on!? What is different with the predefined BasicEffect from the one I instantiate myself? When I inspect the properties of the two instances they seem to be all the same.

[image]

1. How it looks with the "default" BasicEffect
2. How it looks when I instantiate a new BasicEffect

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the differences?

Comment: Have you tried gamedev.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Ah, thanks @Picacodigos ! I've posted it there too. Will spare stackoverflow any future XNA questions!

Comment: What is the code used to draw screenshot 1? In it, it doesn't look like lighting is enabled.

Comment: We need to see more code. Are you assigning your model's textures to the effect?

Comment: Lighting is indeed enabled and there are no textures, just materials. And I ues that's my problem: somewhere in the content pipeline, a BasicEffect is created with information about the meterial color. How I will go ahead and mimic that myself is soething I'd really like to learn! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create the whole effect again, just modify the properties you need to on the original `Effect` property of the `ModelMeshPart`.

So instead of:

```
var basicEffect = new BasicEffect( game.GraphicsDevice );
basicEffect.EnableDefaultLighting();
foreach (var mesh in _modelHead.Meshes)
    foreach (var part in mesh.MeshParts)
        part.Effect = basicEffect;
```

Do this:

```
foreach (var mesh in _modelHead.Meshes)
    foreach (var part in mesh.MeshParts)
        ((BasicEffect)part.Effect).EnableDefaultLighting();
```

This will preserve the specular and diffuse color which have been lost by using the first method, and save on code space.

Also, because each `ModelMeshPart` can have its own material this makes sure you don't lose any of the data you want to keep.

Comment: The "real" reason I asked is because I didn't understand why BasicEffect could draw my models with correct colors, while all color information seemd to get lost once I tried to write my own effects. So the answer that the default BasicEffect is instantiated in the content pipeline based on the model's material colors was the answer I was looking for!